# code line parameters turns into comment in fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I’m trying to debug a program in visual studio with fortran compiler and using mkl library (symmetric matrix solvers by CG) and I face into these errors:

[image: Text] 
[image]

I thought its because of codeline’s length that is too large and code turns into comments with green colour. I searched a lot and I tried this method below,but it didn’t work:

[image: code line parameters turns into comment in fortran]

[image: code line parameters turns into comment in fortran]

Visual Studio 2010

intel parallel studio 2013

Can you help me with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
!   Copyright(C) 2005-2012 Intel Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
!   
!   The source code, information  and  material ("Material") contained herein is
!   owned  by Intel Corporation or its suppliers or licensors, and title to such
!   Material remains  with Intel Corporation  or its suppliers or licensors. The
!   Material  contains proprietary information  of  Intel or  its  suppliers and
!   licensors. The  Material is protected by worldwide copyright laws and treaty
!   provisions. No  part  of  the  Material  may  be  used,  copied, reproduced,
!   modified, published, uploaded, posted, transmitted, distributed or disclosed
!   in any way  without Intel's  prior  express written  permission. No  license
!   under  any patent, copyright  or  other intellectual property rights  in the
!   Material  is  granted  to  or  conferred  upon  you,  either  expressly,  by
!   implication, inducement,  estoppel or  otherwise.  Any  license  under  such
!   intellectual  property  rights must  be express  and  approved  by  Intel in
!   writing.
!   
!   *Third Party trademarks are the property of their respective owners.
!   
!   Unless otherwise  agreed  by Intel  in writing, you may not remove  or alter
!   this  notice or  any other notice embedded  in Materials by Intel or Intel's
!   suppliers or licensors in any way.
!
!*******************************************************************************
!  Content: Intel MKL RCI (P)CG Fortran-77 example
!
!*******************************************************************************

!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Example program for solving symmetric positive definite system of equations.
!  Simplest case: no preconditioning and no the user-defined stopping tests.
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      PROGRAM rci_pcg_f77_test_1
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INCLUDE 'mkl_rci.fi'
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Define arrays for the upper triangle of the coefficient matrix and rhs vector
! Compressed sparse row storage is used for sparse representation
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      INTEGER N, RCI_request, itercount, expected_itercount, i
      PARAMETER (N=9)
      PARAMETER (expected_itercount=9)
      DOUBLE PRECISION  rhs(N), INITIAL_TIME, END_TIME, TIME
      INTEGER IA(10)
      INTEGER JA(33)
      DOUBLE PRECISION A(33)
! Fill all arrays containing matrix data.
      DATA IA /1,4,8,11,15,20,24,27,31,34/
      DATA JA /1,2,4,1,2,3,5,2,3,6,1,4,5,7,2,4,5,6,8,3,5,6,9,4,7,8,5,7,8,9,6,8,9/
      DATA A /2,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,2,-1,-1,-1,3,-1,-1,-1,4/
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Allocate storage for the solver ?par and the initial solution vector
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      INTEGER length
      PARAMETER (length=256)
      DOUBLE PRECISION expected_sol(N)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Some additional variables to use with the RCI (P)CG solver
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DOUBLE PRECISION  solution(N)
      DATA expected_sol/150,100,75,100,75,50,75,50,0/
      INTEGER ipar(length)
      DOUBLE PRECISION dpar(length),TMP(N,4)
      DOUBLE PRECISION DNRM2, Euclidean_norm
      EXTERNAL DNRM2
      CALL CPU_TIME(INITIAL_TIME)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Initialize the right hand side through matrix-vector product
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      rhs(1)=100
      rhs(N)=-100
       !CALL MKL_DCSRSYMV('U', N, A, IA, JA, expected_sol, rhs)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Initialize the initial guess
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       DO I=1, N
         solution(I)=1.D0
       ENDDO
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Initialize the solver
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      CALL dcg_init(N, solution,rhs, RCI_request,ipar,dpar,TMP)
      IF (RCI_request .NE. 0 ) GOTO 999
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Set the desired parameters:
! LOGICAL parameters:
! do residual stopping test
! do not request for the user defined stopping test
! DOUBLE PRECISION parameters
! set the relative tolerance to 1.0D-5 instead of default value 1.0D-6
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ipar(9)=1
      ipar(10)=0
      dpar(1)=1.D-5
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Check the correctness and consistency of the newly set parameters
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      CALL dcg_check(N,solution,rhs,RCI_request,ipar,dpar,TMP)
      IF (RCI_request .NE. 0 ) GOTO 999
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Compute the solution by RCI (P)CG solver without preconditioning
! Reverse Communications starts here
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     CALL dcg(N,solution,rhs,RCI_request,ipar,dpar,TMP)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! If RCI_request=0, then the solution was found with the required precision
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      IF (RCI_request .EQ. 0) THEN
          GOTO 700
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! If RCI_request=1, then compute the vector A*TMP(:,1)
! and put the result in vector TMP(:,2)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ELSEIF (RCI_request .EQ. 1) THEN
        CALL MKL_DCSRSYMV('U', N, A, IA, JA, TMP, TMP(1,2))
        GOTO 1
      ELSE
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! If RCI_request=anything else, then dcg subroutine failed
! to compute the solution vector: solution(N)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        GOTO 999
      ENDIF
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Reverse Communication ends here
! Get the current iteration number
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
700   CALL dcg_get(N,solution,rhs,RCI_request,ipar,dpar,TMP,itercount)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Print solution vector: solution(N) and number of iterations: itercount
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      WRITE(*, *) ' The system has been solved '
      WRITE(*, *) ' The following solution obtained '
      WRITE(*,800) (solution(i),i =1,N)
      WRITE(*, *) ' expected solution '
      WRITE(*,800)(expected_sol(i),i =1,N)
800   FORMAT(3(F10.3))
      WRITE(*,900)(itercount)
900   FORMAT(' Number of iterations: ',1(I2))
      DO I=1,N
         expected_sol(I)=expected_sol(I)-solution(I)
      ENDDO

      Euclidean_norm=DNRM2(N,expected_sol,1)
      WRITE(*, *)
      WRITE(*, *) ' The Norm of error is: '
      WRITE(*, 1000) Euclidean_norm
1000  FORMAT(E11.3)
      CALL CPU_TIME(END_TIME)
      TIME = END_TIME - INITIAL_TIME
      PRINT*, 'The Project Time is: ', TIME
      pause
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Release internal MKL memory that might be used for computations
! NOTE: It is important to call the routine below to avoid memory leaks
! unless you disable MKL Memory Manager
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      CALL MKL_FREEBUFFERS

      IF (itercount.EQ.expected_itercount .AND.
     1                                   Euclidean_norm.LE.1.0D-12) THEN
         WRITE( *,'(A,A)') 'This example has successfully PASSED',
     1 ' through all steps of computation!'
         STOP 0
      ELSE
         WRITE( *,'(A,A,A,I5,A,A,A,E12.5,A)') 'This example may have',
     1 ' FAILED as either the number of iterations differs from the',
     2 ' expected number of iterations ',expected_itercount,' or the',
     3 ' computed solution differs much from the expected solution (',
     4 'Euclidean norm is ',Euclidean_norm,'), or both.'
         STOP 1
      ENDIF
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Release internal MKL memory that might be used for computations
! NOTE: It is important to call the routine below to avoid memory leaks
! unless you disable MKL Memory Manager
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------
999   WRITE( *,'(A,A)') 'This example FAILED as the solver has',
     1 ' returned the ERROR code', RCI_request
      CALL MKL_FREEBUFFERS
      STOP 1

      END
```

Comment: While the linked answer does solve your problem please appreciate that the source form and style of code is 30 years out of date - a nice clean example of 30 years out of date code I admit, but I suggest you spend some time learning about Fortran 95 and later, rather than writing something which is really Fortan 77 in spirit.

Comment: it's my university homework,and i have to run this program in fortran because CMG Suite application is comptaible just with this versions.

Comment: The version of the compiler is from 2013, which is easily new enough to allow you to use Modern Fortran.

Comment: please try to use